# Karate: Store result of a contains check into a variable OR define contains X || Y

Tags: karate

Is it possible to either:

1. Store the boolean result of a contains into a variable, e.g:

```
* def myVariable = foo.response contains
"""
[
  {name: "name1", 
   group: "groupX"
  }, 
  {name: "name2", 
   group: "groupY"
  }
]
"""
```

OR

2. Specify a match ... contains that contains "this" || "that", e.g:

```
def possibility1 = [{name: "name1", group: "groupX"}, {name: "name2", group: "groupY"}]
def possibility2 = [{name: "name1", group: "groupY"}, {name: "name2", group: "groupX"}]
match foo.response contains possibility1 || foo.response contains possibility2
```